# compile python .py file without executing

Tags: python

Is there a way to compile a Python .py file from the command-line **without** executing it?

I am working with an application that stores its python extensions in a non-standard path with  limited permissions and I'd like to compile the files during installation.  I don't need the overhead of Distutils.

Comment: What's wrong with just storing the .py files? Compilation is completely optional.

Comment: also distutils is hardly overhead

Comment: @nosklo: it's called faster start-up time.

Comment: @nosklo: when packaging for a debian repo (like what I am doing in this instance), if I can save from having to worry about distutils, I try to.

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607283/how-can-i-manually-generate-a-pyc-file-from-a-py-file

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> The [py_compile](http://docs.python.org/library/py_compile.html) module provides a function to generate a byte-code file from a source file, and another function used when the module source file is invoked as a script.

```
python -m py_compile fileA.py fileB.py fileC.py
```

Comment: I can’t find where the compiled file goes to.

Comment: output file goes to __pycache__ dir

Answer (score 21):

Yes, there is module [compileall](http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html#module-compileall). Here's an example that compiles all the `.py` files in a directory (but not sub-directories):

```
python -m compileall -l myDirectory
```

Answer (score 5):

In fact if you're on Linux you may already have a `/usr/bin/py_compilefiles` command in your PATH. It wraps the the py_compile module mentioned by other people. If you're not on Linux, here's the [script code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/python-central/trusty/view/head:/py_compilefiles).

Comment: +1 for the interesting info but I'd rather not rely on this script being present (or not).

Comment: The link is broken. If it's possible to fix, please fix.

Answer (score 4):

`$ python -c "import py_compile; py_compile.compile('yourfile.py')"`

or

`$ python -c "import py_compile; py_compile.compileall('dir')"`

Comment: hmmm... the solution proposed by @Roger Pate appears cleanly but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to choose the output location of pyc (by @Jensen Taylor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41725890/4710226)),
you can also specify a source file name you like for traceback if you don't want the absolute path of py file to be written in the pyc:

```
python -c "import py_compile; py_compile.compile('src.py', 'dest.pyc', 'whatever_you_like')"
```

Though "compileall -d destdir" can do the trick too, it will limit your working directory sometimes.
For example, if you want source file name in pyc to be "./src.py", you have to move working directory
to the folder of src.py, which is undesirable in some cases, then run something like "python -m compileall -d ./ ."

Answer (score 1):

I would say something like this, so you can compile it to your chosen location:

```
import py_compile
py_compile(filename+".py",wantedlocation+wantedname+".pyc")
```

As I have now done in my Python project on github.com/lolexorg/Lolex-Tools