# How can you have the Python 3.x incompatibilities without executing your code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-warnings

when doing a `python --help` you have :

```
-3     : warn about Python 3.x incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot trivially fix
```

When doing `python -3 hello.py` , checks are done but your hello.py is executed. [I've seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042426/compile-python-py-file-without-executing) that you can just compile your .py code without executing it using `py_compile` module, but you can't call the `-3` option with `py_compile`. How can you have all those warnings without actually running your python code ?

Comment: Did you try to run 2to3 on the source file?

Comment: @uselpa 2to3 transform your .py to 3.x compatible files. It does not warn like `python -3` . Example : for the same .py file, with `2to3` I have no warning, with `python -3` I have : `DeprecationWarning: The 'new' module has been removed in Python 3.0; use the 'types' module instead`

Comment: that's a good question, maybe we'll just have to keep an eye on http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyLint-3k