# Is compiling untrusted code in CPython considered safe?

Tags: python, security, python-3.x

In Python its possible to compile a Python script without executing (using `py_compile` module, `Py_CompileString` in C).

A lot is written on issues attempting to sand-box CPython (and how difficult it is), however, I'm interested to know if there are known security risks in *compiling* CPython code (without executing its contents).

Put differently, are there known security rests with running:

```
python -m py_compile file_from_unknown_source.py
```

In this case a bad actor may be able to find exploits in the parser or byte-code generator, my question is regarding this and if there are known exploits to do such a task, or if this is generally considered safe.

---

For the purpose of this question, safe means:

- Not be able to run arbitrary Python code or shell commands.
- Not be able to delete, create or access files
  *(besides the compiled `pyc` of course)*.
- Not be able to use the network connection on the system.

In short, not do *anything* besides compiling the code, or failing to compile with invalid input.

Comment: What do you mean by *"safe"*?

Comment: Added some clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compile python .py file without executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042426/compile-python-py-file-without-executing)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042426/compile-python-py-file-without-executing

Comment: This is not a duplicate, The question is about the security implication of compiling untrusted code without executing. NOT asking how to compile without executing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not safe. CPython has lots of known bugs that lead to stack overflows and other nasty conditions. A SIGSEGV should be considered potentially exploitable.

Comment: Could you reference one thats unresolved and can be triggered only by compiling? (not executing).

Comment: Are there known exploits? Or is this more of a hypothetical/potential risk?