# Running python script with Sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Message appearing on Sublime text

[image]

Trying to find an editor for Python, I downloaded Sublime Text 3. Now, I try to run a simple Python script - it is print("Hello World") - in Sublime Text 3, but nothing appears. After seeking, I found that I have to modify the file python27.sublime-build, which we should normally find by clicking "Preferences" and "Browse Packages...", but the problem is I don't see a file with this name.

Here is my script :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gQGA.png)

Comment: execute: Ctrl+B

Comment: The packages that Sublime ships with are stored in a different location than the one you're referencing; that path is for packages you installed yourself (and overrides to existing packages).  That said, Sublime doesn't ship with a file by that name, so whatever you found is probably telling you to create that file. You can create it in the `User` directory found in the place you get to by using that menu entry you referenced in your question.

Comment: Eyllanesc: of course I already tried to execute Ctrl+B

Comment: OdaNurd : my problem is not that Sublime Text doesn't find this file. The problem is that nothing appears when I run my script.

Comment: Can you show us the script? It's possible there's a problem there.

Comment: Yes, click on the link in my first message.

Comment: it seems you have changed your build system to compile the file without executing it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042426/compile-python-py-file-without-executing